# Why does Emacs complain about void-variable displayed-year in my .emacs file?

Tags: emacs, elisp, dot-emacs

I'm trying to implement the solar terms in my `.emacs` so my "holidays" will display the time when the solar longitude crosses each multiple of 15 degrees.  Here is the relevant snipplet.

```
(defun next-solar-term-date (d)
  (solar-date-next-longitude d 15))

(defconst solar-term-names
  ["moderate cold" "severe cold" "spring commerces"
   "rain water" "insects awaken" "vernal equinox"
   "Ching Ming" "corn rain" "summer commerces"
   "corn forms" "corn on ear" "summer solstice"
   "minor heat" "great heat" "autumn commerces"
   "end of heat" "white dew" "autumnal equinox"
   "cold dew" "frost" "winter commerces"
   "light snow" "heavy snow" "winter solstice"])

(setq solar-terms-holidays
      (let* ((k 0) (mylist nil))
        (dotimes (k 4);k=season
          (let* ((j 0))
            (dotimes (j 5);no equinoxes/solstices --- use solar for them
              (let* ((i (+ j (* 6 k)))
                     (month (+ 1 (/ i 2)))
                     (astronextdate (next-solar-term-date
                                     (calendar-astro-from-absolute
                                      (+ (* 15 i)
                                         (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian
                                          (list 1 1 displayed-year))))))
                     (s (aref solar-term-names i))
                     (absnextdate (calendar-absolute-from-astro
                                   astronextdate))
                     (gregnextdate (calendar-gregorian-from-absolute
                                    (floor absnextdate)))
                     (compt (* 24 (- absnextdate (floor absnextdate))))
                     (str (concat s " "
                                  (solar-time-string
                                   compt (if (dst-in-effect absnextdate)
                                             calendar-daylight-time-zone-name
                                           calendar-standard-time-zone-name))))
                     (d (extract-calendar-day gregnextdate)))
                (setq mylist (append mylist
                                     (list
                                      (list 'holiday-fixed month d str))))))))
        mylist))
```

However, emacs (version 23.2-r2 on Gentoo) complains about displayed-year being a void-variable at start-up, and trying to generate the calendar with <kbd>M-x calendar RET</kbd> doesn't help either.  Any idea how I can fix that?  (Certainly not with defining displayed-year in my `.emacs` since this definitely screws up everything else...)

Comment: Did you require in calendar and load it before running this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation needs to be deferred until `displayed-year` is available, which may be achieved by replacing the last expression in your paste with these two:

```
(defun solar-term (i month)
  (let* ((astronextdate (next-solar-term-date
                         (calendar-astro-from-absolute
                          (+ (* 15 i)
                             (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian
                              (list 1 1 displayed-year))))))
         (s (aref solar-term-names i))
         (absnextdate (calendar-absolute-from-astro
                       astronextdate))
         (gregnextdate (calendar-gregorian-from-absolute
                        (floor absnextdate)))
         (compt (* 24 (- absnextdate (floor absnextdate))))
         (str (concat s " "
                      (solar-time-string
                       compt (if (dst-in-effect absnextdate)
                                 calendar-daylight-time-zone-name
                               calendar-standard-time-zone-name))))
         (d (extract-calendar-day gregnextdate)))
    (holiday-fixed month d str)))

(setq solar-terms-holidays
      (let* ((mylist nil))
        (dotimes (k 4)    ;k=season
          (dotimes (j 5)  ;no equinoxes/solstices --- use solar for them
            (let* ((i (+ j (* 6 k)))
                   (month (+ 1 (/ i 2))))
              (push `(solar-term ,i ,month) mylist))))
        mylist))
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you have not bound the symbol `displayed-year` to a value.  Check out the last line in the `let*` binding for `astronextdate`:

```
                                      (list 1 1 displayed-year))))))
```

That symbol isn't bound to any value, so you get a void variable error.  The variable is defined in the `calendar` library which has the documentation:

```
;; A note on free variables:

;; The calendar passes around a few dynamically bound variables, which
;; unfortunately have rather common names.  They are meant to be
;; available for external functions, so the names can't be changed.

;; displayed-month, displayed-year: bound in calendar-generate, the
;;   central month of the 3 month calendar window
```

So, it looks like you just need to add:

```
(require 'calendar)
```

to force Emacs to load the package which defines the variable before hand.

That said, it'll be defined, but not yet bound.  You should change your code to not assume a statically bound `solar-terms-holidays`, but should turn it into a function which calculates those on demand, because the `displayed-year` is only bound when calendar is actually running...

So, one possible solution is to do the following, wrap your `setq` as follows to ensure the variables are bound like you're expecting them to be:

```
(save-window-excursion
  (calendar)
  (setq solar-terms-holidays
        ....)
  (calendar-exit))
```

Comment: You have to do more than just `(require 'calendar)`, you have to actually run the `calendar` function.

Comment: @GarethRees Yah, I was adding that as you were typing your comment.  :)  And we both edited the question at the same time.  Guess we're in sync.

Comment: Forgot to add --- I have (require 'calendar) at the beginning of my .emacs file, but emacs still complains.

Comment: @KK Yes, which is why I said you should change your code to not assume a statically bound variable, but should turn it into a function which you run at the appropriate time.  Or... I'll add another possible solution.